# status equations of 2° order circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

I have a problem with this circuit

[image]

I can't write the status equation because the system that characterizes the circuit is coupled respect to derivatives of the difference of rings currents.

Let $$i_1:=i_{R_1}=i_{L_1}$$ $$i_2:=i_{R_2}$$ so, applying counterclockwise the KVLs to the two rings we obtain

$$\begin{cases}
L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1-L_2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}[i_2-i_1]+R_1 i_1=0 \\
L_2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}[i_2-i_1]-e+R_2 i_2=0 \\
\end{cases}$$

or, equivalently

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1=-\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2} i_1+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2=-\frac{R_2}{L_2}i_2+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1+e \\
\end{cases}$$

but now I don't know how to proceed to determinate the vectorial status equation $$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$$

Comment: Just use substitution (i.e. replace \$di_2/dt\$ from the first equation with the second equation). You will be able to represent the currents derivatives in terms of currents and \$e\$.

Comment: @Vicente Cunha, that will still leave \$i_2\$ in the equation.

Comment: @Chu \$x\$ is a vertical vector with both \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$; should I expand these comments to an answer?

Comment: @Vicente Cunha, state space form would be a very useful answer

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your equations:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1=-\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2} i_1+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2=-\frac{R_2}{L_2}i_2+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1+e \\
\end{cases}$$

Substitution of second equation into first equation, and of first equation into second:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1=-\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2} i_1+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\left(-\frac{R_2}{L_2}i_2+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1+e\right) \\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2=-\frac{R_2}{L_2}i_2+\left(-\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2} i_1+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2\right)+e \\
\end{cases}$$

Rewriting equations:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1\times\left(1-\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\right)= -\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2}i_1-\frac{R_2}{L_1+L_2}i_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}e\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2\times\left(1-\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2}\right)= -\frac{R_1}{L_1+L_2}i_1 -\frac{R_2}{L_2}i_2 + e\\
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_1\times L_1= -R_1i_1-R_2i_2+L_2e\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}i_2\times L_1= -R_1i_1 -\frac{(L_1+L_2)R_2}{L_2}i_2 + (L_1+L_2)e\\
\end{cases}$$

Matrix representation:

$$
A = \frac{1}{L_1}\left( \begin{array}{cc}
-R_1 & -R_2 \\ -R_1 & -\frac{(L_1+L_2)R_2}{L_2} \end{array} \right)
$$

$$
B = \frac{1}{L_1}\left( \begin{array}{c}
L_2 \\ L_1+L_2 \end{array} \right)
$$